ORACLE SQL Select Query but to not include 2 variables
I'm trying to write a basic select query to give me all the displayed records from my DB but I want to exclude ones that fall in to two specific categories.
Select * from opr_operation WHERE MCC = '987' AND NOT (NAME like '%abcd%' and COUNTRY is = 123)
So I have tried to use the above but I can't get it to work.
I basically would like a full output from OPR_OPERATION where MCC = 987 but to not include any entries where the name has part of the start of the alphabet in (abcd onwards) and it also has the country as 123.
Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Just get rid of the 'is':
SELECT *
FROM opr_operation
WHERE MCC = '987'
  AND NOT (NAME LIKE '%abcd%' AND COUNTRY = 123);


Ah perfect! I have been playing round with that for ages! Thanks
